# arrange one below the other every 2 columns from data frame in R

Tags: r

Hi I have a df as below which show date and their respected

```
date   1_val   date  2_val  . . . .  date  n_val  
  2014   23      2014  33    . . . .  2014   34
  2015   22      2016  12    . . . .  2016   99
```

i have tried with hard coding to arrange the columns one below the other

```
for 1&2 columns
a=1
b=2
names_2<-df[,c(a,b)]
colnames(names_2)[1]<-"Date"
names_2 <- names_2[!apply(is.na(names_2) | names_2 == "", 1, all),]
names_2<-melt(names_2,id=colnames(names_2)[1])
samp_out<-names_2

for 3&4 columns
a=3
b=4
names_2<-df[,c(a,b)]
colnames(names_2)[1]<-"Date"
names_2 <- names_2[!apply(is.na(names_2) | names_2 == "", 1, all),]
names_2<-melt(names_2,id=colnames(names_2)[1])
samp_out1<-names_2 

till n-numbers
df1= rbind(samp_out,samp_out1,......samp_out_n)
```

output

```
 date   variable   value
2014     1_val       23
2015     1_val       22
2014     2_val       33
2016     2_val       12
.
.
2014     n_val      34
2016     n_val      99
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the untidy rectangle

```
library(magrittr)
csv <- "date,1_val,date,2_val,date,3_val  
  2014,23,2014,33,2014,34
  2015,22,2016,12,2016,99"
```

Read into a data frame, then transform into a long/eav rectangle.

```
ds_eav <- csv %>%   
  readr::read_csv() %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column(var="height") %>% 
  tidyr::gather(key=key, value=value, -height)
```

*output*:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 4
     key index value height
   <chr> <int> <int>  <int>
 1  date     1  2014      1
 2  date     1  2015      2
 3 value     1    23      1
 4 value     1    22      2
 5  date     2  2014      1
 6  date     2  2016      2
 7 value     2    33      1
 8 value     2    12      2
 9  date     3  2014      1
10  date     3  2016      2
11 value     3    34      1
12 value     3    99      2
```

Identify which rows are dates/values.  Then shift up dates' index by 1.

```
ds_eav <- ds_eav %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(
    index_val  = sub("^(\\d+)_val$" , "\\1", key),
    index_date = sub("^date_(\\d+)$", "\\1", key),
    index_date = dplyr::if_else(key=="date", "0", index_date),
    key        = dplyr::if_else(grepl("^date(_\\d+)*", key), "date", "value"),
    index      = dplyr::if_else(key=="date", index_date, index_val),
    index      = as.integer(index),
    index      = index + dplyr::if_else(key=="date", 1L, 0L)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::select(key, index, value, height)
```

Follow the advice of @jarko-dubbeldam and use spread/gather on the last step too

```
ds_eav %>% 
  tidyr::spread(key=key, value=value)
```

*output*:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  index height  date value
* <int>  <int> <int> <int>
1     1      1  2014    23
2     1      2  2015    22
3     2      1  2014    33
4     2      2  2016    12
5     3      1  2014    34
6     3      2  2016    99
```

You can use `paste0(index, "_val")` to get you exact output.  But I'd prefer to keep them as integers, so you can do math on them in necessary (eg, `max()`).

*edit 1*: incorporate the advice & corrections of @jarko-dubbeldam and @hnskd.
*edit 2*: use `rownames_to_column()` in case the input isn't a balanced rectangle (eg, one column doesn't all all the rows).

Comment: If you are going to go with the tidyverse method, take a look at `tidyr::gather`. It does similar things to `melt` in my answer.

Comment: Some of the rows/observations of your output are redundant. For instance, row 2 should not exist (since it does not correspond to any parts of the original dataframe). This is the same for row 3, 6, 7 etc.

Comment: You're both right, @jarko-dubbeldam and @HNSKD.  Thanks. I added the `height` variable to facilitate your corrections.

Comment: Still overly compilated. See this as a solution: `ds_eav %>% gather(key = "year", val = "val", '1_val', '2_val', '3_val')`

Comment: Would that work if one column wasn't complete?  Also, I'm getting the error: "Error: Strings must match column names. Unknown columns: 1_val"

Answer (score 1):

The function `melt` in the package `data.table` does that:

```
melt(df, id = "Date", measure = patterns("_val"))
```

You can specify the name of the variable to pivot on (Date in this case) and a pattern in the variables you want to keep the values of. You can also supply a vector with all the variablenames instead.

```
> DT <- data.table(Date = c(2014,2013), `1_val` = c(33, 32), Date = c(2014, 2013), `2_val` = c(65, 34))
> DT
   Date 1_val Date 2_val
1: 2014    33 2014    65
2: 2013    32 2013    34
> melt(DT, id = "Date", measure = patterns("_val"))
   Date variable value
1: 2014    1_val    33
2: 2013    1_val    32
3: 2014    2_val    65
4: 2013    2_val    34
```

Comment: That's a lot more concise than mine.  I'm curious, what code created  `df` and `DT`?  What were the different names of the date columns in df?

Comment: Hmm, I used `df` at first because that is how OP specified it. I am not sure what happened to the second Date in my example. Let me get back to it.

Comment: @wibeasley Added

Comment: Thanks jarko what if my col's dont follow pattern , can we use    melt(DT, id = "Date", measure = !patterns("_val"))

Comment: @SrmMurty You could also specify the columns like this: `measure = c("columnname1", "columnname2", ....)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stack` from base R,

```
setNames(data.frame(stack(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)])[1], 
                    stack(df[c(FALSE, TRUE)])), 
       c('date', 'value', 'variable'))

#  date value variable
#1 2014    33    1_val
#2 2013    32    1_val
#3 2014    65    2_val
#4 2013    34    2_val
```

Comment: i am getting error as   "Error in stack.data.frame(df[c(TRUE, FALSE)]) : 
  no vector columns were selected "